# Open Span tag on image click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to open, show and close the others span tags when i click its specific image.

```js
$("#img1").on('click', function() {
  $("#div1").fadeIn();
  $("#div2,#div3").fadeOut();
});
$("#img2").on('click', function() {
  $("#div2").fadeIn();
  $("#div1,#div3").fadeOut();
});
$("#img3").on('click', function() {
  $("#div3").fadeIn();
  $("#div1,#div2").fadeOut();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="css/imagens/missao2.png" alt="missao" id="img1" />
<img src="css/imagens/missao2.png" alt="missao" id="img2" />
<img src="css/imagens/missao2.png" alt="missao" id="img3" />

<span id="div1" style="display:none;position:absolute;border:3px solid blue;">Span 1</span>
<span id="div2" style="display:none;position:absolute;border:3px solid blue;">Span 2</span>
<span id="div3" style="display:none;position:absolute;border:3px solid blue;">Span 3</span>
```

Comment: What does "open span tag" mean exactly? show?

Comment: It seems to work ... http://jsfiddle.net/rfornal/0pgxp9ov/ (changed text in spans) ...

Comment: Your original code wasn't linking to the jQuery library. j08691 added it in and your code not works on the StackOverflow editor. Try adding the jQuery library link to your page, your verify it's correct (if already linked).

Comment: Try to use more readable text: _http://jsfiddle.net/jkup9Lsy/_

Comment: your code is perfectly working http://jsfiddle.net/u7c5u8o6/

Comment: thanks but its not working, it dont do nothing :(

Comment: @RicardoSimoes What browser are you using? That code is working for everyone except you, so that implies an issue on your end.

Comment: @AoN Im using firefox, could any of the other code be messing with this?

Comment: This is inside a P tag can it be because of this?                                                                                                         <p class="txt_h" style="display:none;">
     
</p>

Comment: also txt_h is defined like this  texto2 = $(this).children('.txt_h').html();

Comment: @RicardoSimoes Is your problem with displaying `.txt_h` or with displaying the `span` elements?

Comment: @AoN the span element, the txt_h works fine and shows the images but dont do nothing when i click them. the txt_h was just to let you guys know that this is inside a similar situation.

Comment: @RicardoSimoes Sorry for the slow reply, someone lit the library at my work on fire. Mackan has updated his answer to show it should work with the `.txt_h` have a display trigger. Perhaps we can be a bit more productive from a chat.

Comment: it seems i cant go to chat :s the problem must be some in page code block

Answer (score 0):

Works fine - if you just include jQuery (that you hadn't done, but someone edited it in for you)

*Well, there's still an outstanding question as to what you mean by "open a span tag", but I'll assume `show`.*

Edit:

I saw from comments that your code is inside a `p` with style `display:none`. This won't work, since the entire block will be hidden/not displayed, including any elements inside. Skip the `display:none` in the wrapper (the outer `p`)!

```
<p class="txt_h"><!-- code here is fine --></p>
```

As an alternative, you can toggle the visibility of the outer `p` when an item is clicked. See snippet below for that.

```js
$('#showthings').click(function() {
  $('.txt_h').show();
});

$("#img1").on('click', function() {
  $("#div1").fadeIn();
  $("#div2,#div3").fadeOut();
});
$("#img2").on('click', function() {
  $("#div2").fadeIn();
  $("#div1,#div3").fadeOut();
});
$("#img3").on('click', function() {
  $("#div3").fadeIn();
  $("#div1,#div2").fadeOut();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="showthings">Click to show images</span>
<p class="txt_h" style="display:none;">
<img src="css/imagens/missao2.png" alt="missao" id="img1" />
<img src="css/imagens/missao2.png" alt="missao" id="img2" />
<img src="css/imagens/missao2.png" alt="missao" id="img3" />

   
<span id="div1" style="display:none;position:absolute;border:3px solid blue;">DIV1</span>
<span id="div2" style="display:none;position:absolute;border:3px solid blue;">DIV2</span>
<span id="div3" style="display:none;position:absolute;border:3px solid blue;">DIV3</span>
</p>
```

Comment: everything is inside the p with display none, i need to had this to be an option when that option is visible, p is hidden but when p is visible then i can click the imagen and show the specific span

Comment: in this case nothing will show but theres an option where it puts the  <p class="txt_h" style="display:none;"> visible and i need the show span on img click inside it

Comment: @RicardoSimoes ok, I've simulated your code in my snippet above. It works fine still. What else is missing?

Comment: @RicardoSimoes There are many. You'll have to share more code if you want us to find out. If you have a jquery version below 1.7 this would also make your code not work (no support for `.on`)

Comment: let me make a online demo for all of you to see. brb

Comment: you can find the file here: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=52300876524268223792

Comment: @RicardoSimoes Your code is throwing errors (check the console!). This is far too much code for me to debug, and you have a much easier time doing that yourself. You mix js and php, and if any php doesn't return what you're expecting it will cause errors. Some examples are your `moveright` and `moverDireita` functions. Unescaped php-code that might throw errors, like: `if(ultimo<<?php echo $total; ?>){`. I would  put that php-code in quotes `"`, and make sure it's returning something always. Any errors will likely halt the rest of your js execution, resulting in broken functions and events.

Comment: i understand but i didnt make this page, i use ASP, i was ask to make some changes to this in the html but im having this issue with the code. thanks, ill try to tidy it up.